# Regular expression on tagged words

Tags: java, regex, nlp, opennlp

Given a string representing a sentence like this followed by tagging the string using OpenNLP.

`String sentence = "His plays remain highly popular, and are constantly studied.";`

I get this below. My question is how do I know apply a regular expression to it to filter out tags? What is throwing me off is the word prepended to each hyphen. If it were just tags I can do something like `(VBP|VBN)+` for example, the words in front would vary.

`His_PRP$ plays_NNS remain_VBP highly_RB popular,_JJ and_CC are_VBP constantly_RB studied._VBN`

For example, how would I write a regular expression to keep all `NN` and `CC`? 
So given the tagged string as shown above how do I get `plays_NNS and_CC`?

Comment: Please elaborate about the problem with one example.

Comment: @AnwarShaikh Hope that helps.

Comment: Yes. Thanks, hope my post below answers your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can use regular expressions and extract the desired substrings which matches your pattern and concatenate to get required resultant string.

```
 String text = "His_PRP$ plays_NNS remain_VBP highly_RB popular,_JJ and_CC are_VBP constantly_RB studied._VBN";
 String pattern = "([^\\s]+_(NNS|CC))";
 String resultText = "";

    // Create a Pattern object
    Pattern r = Pattern.compile(pattern);

    // Now create matcher object.
    Matcher m = r.matcher(text);
    while (m.find( )) 
    {
      resultText = resultText + m.group(0) + " ";
    }

    System.out.println("RESULT: " + resultText);

    /*
    #### OUTPUT #####
    RESULT: plays_NNS and_CC 
    */
```

Comment: Nice solution, what does this part, `[^\\s]+_` match? Does this basically apply a regular expression `(NN|CC)` or whatever it might be to the text where each "word" in the text is represented by the characters after the `_`? Hopefully this is clear enough to understand.

Comment: Thanks. It matches any character except white space. If you find it as a solution to your question then please accept it as an answer and upvote.

Comment: Is it possible to write a regex to match a NNP followed by NNS?

Comment: I do not want to apply the regular expression to each substring, I want to do it on the entire sentence together.

Comment: 1. Yes. It is possible to write regex that matches NNP followed by NNS. OR you can use same regex and keep a Boolean flag which is `True` when NNP is found and checks if next match is with NNS.

2. Whether you apply it on entire sentence or each substring it won't affect the time complexity. It is convenient to do it this way as you get control over each match. It doesn't matter as long as your entire sentence is stored in a String.

Hope answered your question.

Answer (score 0):

```
[^\s]+_(NNS|CC)
```

This regular expression will help you extract only NNS and CC tags.
You can play with the regexp here:
https://regex101.com/r/x1VxL0/1

Answer (score 0):

Non-regex solution using a filter method.

```
public static void main(String []args){

  String inputText = "His_PRP$ plays_NNS remain_VBP highly_RB popular,_JJ and_CC are_VBP constantly_RB studied._VBN";

  String[] tags = {"_NN", "_CC"};
  String[] found = filter(inputText, tags);

  for(int i = 0; i < found.length; i++){
    System.out.println(found[i]);
  }
}
```

```
private static String[] filter(String text, String[] tags){

  String[] words = text.split(" "); // Split words by spaces
  ArrayList<String> results = new ArrayList<String>();

  // Save all words that match any of the provided tags
  for(String word : words){
    for(String tag : tags){
      if(word.contains(tag)){
        results.add(word);
        break;
      }
    }
  }
  return results.toArray(new String[0]); // Return results as a string array
}
```

Prints to the console:

```
plays_NNS                                                                                                                                                           
and_CC
```

Comment: When you return found, it returns a memory address. Also when you return found indexed at 0 you only get a single tag. Its not correct but I  like this approach very much.

Comment: It's not returning found at index 0. I included `new String[0]` as a parameter of `results.toArray()` because `.toArray()` returns an array of type `Object` by default and if you include `new String[0]` it returns a `String[]`

Comment: I know it doesn't return found at index 0, I switched it to that to check the contents of it. It doesn't seem to return an array containing these two strings `"plays_NNS", "and_CC"` though.